# Vertical slider in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
        <div class="carousel thin" style="height: 300px;">
            <a class="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>
            <div class="window">
                <ul class="clr">     
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>

                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>

                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>
                     <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>
                     <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports" alt="#Img desc#" width="150" height="150">
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div> <!-- .window -->
            <a class="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
        </div> <!-- .carousel -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">
        <h2>Vertical Bootstrap Carousel-Snippet</h2></br>
        <h3>by Andreas Nemeseri, Bootsnippet by Tobias Zimmermann</h3>
        <p>http://nemeseri.com/ender-carousel/</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is the html for the vertical slider.

The fiddle for the carousels : https://jsfiddle.net/0kr57bnm/

In the mentioned fiddle, you can see that there are 2 more sliders along with this. The last slider is the one I am talking about. When the page has just the vertical slider, it works. But when along with the other 2 carousels, its navigation buttons do not work. Also I am not able to change the width of the carousel.

I have used the code for vertical slider from https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/k2dz3

Where am I going wrong?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try updating the fiddle with HTML only for the the vertical slider. It seems to work fine when the horizontal sliders were removed.

Comment: @DanPhilip my problem is that exactly. It is working fine alone, but not when it is with the other carousels. I need it to be with the other carousels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vertical slider you forgot to initialize the carousel.

**In jQuery onload add:**

```
$(".vertical").carousel({
    vertical: true
});
```

Change the div for vertical carousel from:

`<div class="carousel thin" style="height: 300px;">`

to

`<div class="carousel thin vertical" style="height: 300px;">`